# Не запускается локальная база данных MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

При попытке запуска базы возникает ошибка

```
mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset>

Active: failed (Result: signal) since Mon 2023-02-13 14:32:43 +05; 11s ago

Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual

Process: 3267 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=kil>
|Main PID: 3267 (code=killed, signal=ILL)

CPU: 13ms
```

Сейчас вот выдало процесс 3267, до этого был Process: 647

Кто подскажет как быть?

Переустановка базы заново результатов не дало

Comment: Почитайте вот это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68609678/mongodb-result-signal-code-killed-signal-ill и вот это https://qna.habr.com/q/1084400 может что полезное найдётся

Answer (score 0):

Помогли ссылки выше. Снес 6 версию и установил 4. Все работает.